# How to synchronize data between two tables in different databases

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, distributed-system

My problem statement is as below :

So, we have a system A where we get things from system C. Records coming in from system C are dumped into database of system A. One main aspect of that incoming record is it has Status field with values as (Synchronised, Not Available, Unable to synchronize).

Also, we have system B in place where records from system A are saved.

**Now the main point here is** as soon as there is update in system A's records status the same should be updated in system B's database table.

Hence whenever client queries for data from system B it will have the most recent status.

**JUST FYI:** I'm working in .NET Core Web API based projects both system A & B are based on that technology and databases for those individual projects are based on MySQL.

So far I'm still in research mode and till now i have explored on Dotmim sync framework, [Trigger based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132195/synchronize-value-of-column-between-two-tables-in-different-databases) , [The best technology to synchronize data between different database schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451787/the-best-technology-to-synchronize-data-between-different-database-schemas)

Haven't found such concrete and best solution as of now and looking for some fresh pointers or suggestions.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried table replication in MySQL ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha no sir. Need to check this.

Comment: @ErgestBasha both tables at my end has different structure but there is one column common. Will this approach help ?

Comment: I have only used table replication with the same data structure of the table  on both sides. Though [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-differing-tables.html) it says that you can have more columns on the source or on the replica , but the columns order should be the same

Comment: @ErgestBasha Would be great to see the code piece or know about the things that you used [like if stored proc or triggers used] needed to achieve this.

Comment: I'm the author of Dotmim.Sync.
If you need any help about Dotmim.Sync, do not hesitate to start a discussion here (or on Github) I will try to help you out

Answer (score 1):

> Would be great to see the code piece or know about the things that you
> used

Note that below answer works for same definition of the table on both servers.

On Master Server.

Create a replication user with replication grant access:

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user where user='replication_ip_log_2';
+----------------------+---------------+
| user                 | host          |
+----------------------+---------------+
| replication_ip_log_2 | xxx.xx.xx.xx |
+----------------------+---------------+

mysql> show grants for `replication_ip_log_2`@`xxx.xx.xx.xx`;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for replication_ip_log_2@xxx.xx.xx.xx                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replication_ip_log_2'@'xxx.xx.xx.xx' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+


FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; --- Carefully this will lock all tables 
SHOW MASTER STATUS; --- And copy the values of the result of the last command somewhere.
```

You need the file and position

```
File             | Position
mysql-bin.091820 |  7039359
```

Without closing the connection to the client (because it would release the read lock) issue the command to get a dump of the master:

```
mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

Do not  release the lock,  if the dump has not ended yet.

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Now copy the dump file to the slave using scp or your preferred tool.

On Slave Server.

Add  replicate-do-table=db_name.table_name and after the change is made restart mysql service on Slave.

```
sudo grep -ir "ip_log2" /etc/mysql/
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf:replicate-do-table=db_name.ip_log2
```

Open a connection to mysql and type:

```
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE;

CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO
SOURCE_HOST='source_server_ip',
SOURCE_USER='replica_user',
SOURCE_PASSWORD='password',
SOURCE_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.091820', ---the data tou saved from master 
SOURCE_LOG_POS=7039359;
```

Load masters data dump with this console command:

```
mysql -uroot -p < /root/mysqldump.sql
START SLAVE;
SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Have one doubt after looking at this. Does this work automatically...i mean as soon as there is entry in one table of a database it immediately replicates change on another table of different database ?

Comment: @THINKINGMACHINE yes, that is the point of replication. Every change made on the master automaticly will be reflected on the slave

Comment: @THINKINGMACHINE I made a change on `mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql` this will backup only the table you need , not all the databases/tables